# RoR Enum "Unable to autoload constant" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I am getting a basic enum error in active admin:

> Unable to autoload constant School_user

I have defined the enums in the model:

```
class SchoolUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :school

    enum user_type: [:school, :student, :guardian, :teacher]

end
```

And in admin/school_user.rb I am trying to get the dropdown list:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SchoolUser do

permit_params [:user_type]

form do |f|
      f.inputs "School_user" do
        f.input :user_type, :as => :select, :collection => School_user::user_type.keys
    end
    f.actions
end

end
```

user_type is an integer.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here but I bet it's a simple oversight. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to autoload constant School_user

I believe the error is in the below line

```
f.input :user_type, :as => :select, :collection => School_user::user_type.keys
```

where `School_user` should be `SchoolUser`

```
f.input :user_type, :as => :select, :collection => SchoolUser::user_types.keys
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed this but then get an undefined method for user_type error?

Comment: @Co2 Can you post the full error which you got now?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, I just needed to put in user_types.keys instead of user_type.keys. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @co2 aah yes. Didn't see it.